# Empty cylinder geometry for gazebo

Tags: gazebo-all-versions

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,
I want to create a hollow (empty) cylinder on Gazebo. I did not find reference to get this forme / geometry.
I see that only full cylinder is proposed in gazebo.
I have also seen the following link but not found hallow ( empty) cylinder.:

> http://sdformat.org/spec?ver=1.7&elem=geometry

Would you please help me creating it?
Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/26098/empty-cylinder-geometry-for-gazebo/) by [sana](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/34096/sana/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 17 on 2020-11-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

If you want to create complex geometries (i.e. geometries that cannot be obtained by combining full cubes, full cylinders or full spheres), such as an empty cylinder, the only way is by extruding an SVG file. In this case, you have to extrude a circular crown. SVG files can be obtained using several apps, for example **Inkscape**. I recommend you to follow this tutorial ([Extrude SVG files](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=extrude_svg&cat=model_editor_top)).

---

Originally posted by [Simone](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/24349/simone/) with karma: 30 on 2020-11-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0